# I got a null value when exchange value from php to python and back to php

Tags: php, python

I got a null result when exchanging data from my php and python..

here's my code php..

```
<?php $thisurl = 'http://www.kumby.com/avatar-the-last-airbender-book-3-chapter-5/';
  $getUrl = shell_exec('python test2.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($thisurl))); 

  $resultData = json_decode($getUrl, true);
  var_dump($resultData);
  ?>
```

and here is my python code

```
import sys, json
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS

try:
        url = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
except:
        print "ERROR"
        sys.exit(1)

#open and read page
page = urllib.urlopen(url)
html = page.read()
#create BeautifulSoup parse-able "soup"
soup = BS(html)
#get the src attribute from the video tag


        video = soup.find("iframe").get("src")
        print json.dumps(video)
```

Comment: When passing arg - `python test2.py <arg>`. You have missed a space between python script and <arg>

Comment: @HussainTamboli i still get this null result. maybe i shouldn't use the json?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @HussainTamboli now i know why. thanks for this. I re-scan my codes now i know :) thanks bro

Comment: Why i always got an elementary errors HAHA

Comment: @HussainTamboli it was the spaces and indentations. haha. sorry im a newbie. another thing is i dont need to use the json.